# ios Stripe payment(Account to Account Transfer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, stripe-payments

I am making an application in Objective-C(iOS). I want to transfer some amount from my account to the other account using my application.
**Case:** The transfers will be user specific.
1.There will be a user who will post his need for money.
2.The other person who wants to help him will contact him in personal chat.
3.There will be a payment option from where the donator will send money to the person in need.
Please help if anybody is having knowledge about it, as I haven't worked with stripe before.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be setting up **Stripe**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdszUvzroxQ

The tutorial uses **Heroku** which handles the backend side of the payments.
Here is the documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com
Just incase you're looking for a way to do this with **Firebase**, check out my answer here [Swift Firebase Stripe Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239322/swift-firebase-stripe-connect/48239411#48239411)

The next step would be altering your Stripe project to work for **Stripe Connect**

The documentation for **Stripe connect** is here https://stripe.com/docs/connect

You basically need to setup your account to allow for users to sign up as 'Connected accounts' that can receive payments. Your stripe account takes the payment and then dishes out to the connected account accordingly, it needs to be setup in the node server.

Stripe has an example project that uses **Stripe connect** which is what you're looking for, this handles **marketplace** style payments.

Take a look at their project. The concept is that users can sign up online and be accepted for payments.

Here is the project https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides

and the demo website https://rocketrides.io